# Setting up a toolbar with NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-toolbar, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to set up a toolbar for my simple Navigation UI which has neither bottom navigation nor drawer.

Here is the code for my Main Activity layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorTopNavigation"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Testing"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Code for MainActivity

```
class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity(),
    ReaderFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment.navController)

    }

    override fun onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment)
        if (fragment is ReaderFragment) {
        } else if (fragment is ChapterDetailsFragment) {
        }

    }

    override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Navigation graph is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/reader_fragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/reader_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.quran.ReaderFragment"
        android:label="Reader"
        tools:layout="@layout/reader_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_chapters_to_chapterDetails"
            app:destination="@id/chapterDetailsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chapterDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.quran.ChapterDetailsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_chapter_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chapter_details" />
</navigation>
```

and reader fragment is

```
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * [ReaderFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener] interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the [ReaderFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

class ReaderFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, QuranElementClickListener {

    private lateinit var quranElementsListView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var adapter: QuranTextAdapter


    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var interactionListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reader_fragment, container, false)


        val dbAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context)
        dbAccess.open()
        val quranElements = dbAccess.allElements

        quranElementsListView = view.findViewById(R.id.quranElementsListView)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        quranElementsListView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        adapter = QuranTextAdapter(quranElements, this)
        quranElementsListView.adapter = adapter
        return view
    }

    override fun onQuranElementClick(quranElement: QuranElement, position: Int) {
        print(quranElement.arabicText)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_chapters_to_chapterDetails)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        print("This view is clicked")
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            interactionListener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        interactionListener = null
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     *
     *
     * See the Android Training lesson [Communicating with Other Fragments]
     * (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
     * for more information.
     */
    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: String)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ReaderFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            ReaderFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I have already set the a customized toolbar by setting

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorTopNavigation</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTopNavigation</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

Now if I run the project it will show only the toolbar with Reader text and Reader fragment is not loaded and nothing is shown in the recycler view.

[image]

but if I just comment the toolbar in the activity layout file and change the onCreate method in activity to following

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
//        val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
//        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navHostFragment.navController)


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(ReaderFragment(), ReaderFragment::javaClass.toString())
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

then recycler view is visible like this

[image]

But i wanted both the recycler view and the toolbar and i also wanted to customize the toolbar a little bit like custom font. Can someone guide me on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  **android:orientation="vertical"** to your main activity like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:orientation="vertical"  
tools:context=".MainActivity">  
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar   
android:id="@+id/toolbar"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"  
android:background="@color/colorTopNavigation"  
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"   
app:title="Testing" />   
<fragment android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"  
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
app:defaultNavHost="true"  
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />  
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
```